# OSX recovery boot fails

Tags: boot, refind

I installled refind on my macbook pro as I wanted to be able to run Debian on my mac as well.
I disabled CoreStorage on the mac partition to be able to shrink the mac partition as much as I could freeing space for my linux system.
Booting both systems works fine but booting the Recovery either simply fails (whrn pressing R at startup or when selecting the recovery option from refind) or boots the normal OSX system (when pressing option at start up and select "Recovery HD").

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot that... any hints on where to look at?

Comment: Creating the new partition probably messed up with the partition number which neither refind nor the OSX boot loader seemed to like

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258607/refind-boot-macos-from-recovery-hd-fails-how-do-i-get-refind-to-boot-macos-reco